# Liquibase - DBMS specific output's are not captured in log files

Tags: liquibase, sql-scripts

We are using Liquibase 3.5.3. We are looking to capture the DBMS specific outputs in Log files , but none of the above options (--logLevel=debug,Warning,Error,severe) are does that need.

i.e.: while using `select * from table` inside the sql script, the log file has the below

```
DEBUG 1/4/18 11:55 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
DEBUG 1/4/18 11:55 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from customer
DEBUG 1/4/18 11:55 PM: liquibase: Create Database Lock Table
```

But it does not show the result set in the log file, and the same is for "table created", "no of rows updated", etc.

Is there a possibilities to get this done?